# A matter of good looking code (related to passing methods as a parameter)

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I've been reading up on delegate and passing methods as a parameter in C#, simply because my "OCD" is gnawing me when I look at this code:

```
 public static T GetSingleItem<T>(string query, params object[] args) where T : new()
{
    using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(DbPath))
    {
        db.Trace = true;
        return db.Query<T>(query, args).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}

public static List<T> GetItems<T>(string query, params object[] args) where T : new()
{
    using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(DbPath))
    {
        db.Trace = true;
        return db.Query<T>(query, args);
    }
}

public static void Insert(object obj)
{
    using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(DbPath))
    {
        db.Trace = true;
        db.Insert(obj);
    }
}

public static void Update(object obj)
{
    using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(DbPath))
    {
        db.Trace = true;
        db.Update(obj);
   }
}
```

Is there a way to encapsulate the using statement and the db.Trace in one method and then simply call the rest of the methodcontent e.g. db.Update(obj) from their specific methods?

The obvious problem with passing a partial method as a parameter e.g.

```
public static T Runner<T>(Func<T> funcToRun)
```

Is that I'm calling db.Update() from the object instantiated by the using statement.

Any smart solutions to this pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not saying this is the best way to refactor it, but you were almost there with your idea, I've just expanded it.

I believe, but I'm not sure, that this might be called the Template Method pattern (but examples I find of this don't use `Func`, they use virtual methods and derived classes, but the concept is the same).

You need one for void:

```
public static void RunAction(Action<SQLiteConnection> actionToRun)
{
    using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(DbPath))
    {
        db.Trace = true;
        actionToRun(db);
   }
}
```

And one for return types:

```
public static T RunFunc<T>(Func<SQLiteConnection, T> funcToRun) where T : new()
{
    using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(DbPath))
    {
        db.Trace = true;
        return funcToRun(db);
   }
}
```

Calling a void `Action`:

```
public static void Update(object obj)
{
    RunAction(db => db.Update(obj));
}
```

Calling a returning `Func`:

```
public static List<T> GetItems<T>(string query, params object[] args) where T : new()
{
    return RunFunc<List<T>>(db => db.Query<T>(query, args));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the **very** quick response.
I had not passed the db as a parameter.
Code worked fluently, except a minor detail in db.Query<T>. Thank you very much :)